# Autenticar con Firebase en Android mediante un número de teléfono

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy haciendo una app con android studio y estoy haciendo un interfaz de autentitificacion con el numero del movil.

Estoy usa usando este codigo para enviar ma solicitud tal como dice en la documentacion.

```
// [START start_phone_auth]
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
60,                 // Timeout duration
TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
// [END start_phone_auth]
mVerificationInProgress = true;



 mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
                // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
                // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
                //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
                // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
                //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
                //     user action.
                Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);
                // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                mVerificationInProgress = false;
                // [END_EXCLUDE]

                // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                // Update the UI and attempt sign in with the phone credential
                updateUI(STATE_VERIFY_SUCCESS, credential);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
                // for instance if the the phone number format is not valid.
                Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);
                // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                mVerificationInProgress = false;
                // [END_EXCLUDE]

                if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                    // Invalid request
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    mPhoneNumberField.setError("Invalid phone number.");
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                    // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Quota exceeded.",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }

                // Show a message and update the UI
                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                updateUI(STATE_VERIFY_FAILED);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }

            @Override
            public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                                   PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
                // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
                // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
                // by combining the code with a verification ID.
                Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);

                // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
                mVerificationId = verificationId;
                mResendToken = token;

                // [START_EXCLUDE]
                // Update UI
                updateUI(STATE_CODE_SENT);
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
        };

Y este codigo para el inicio de sesion.

 mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                            setup.setUserid(user.getUid());
                            setup.setUsertel(txtcodigoarea.getText().toString()+txttelefono.getText().toString());
                            setup.setUsersimpletel(txttelefono.getText().toString());
                            setup.setVerifiacionid(mVerificationId);
                            setup.setVerificacioncode(verificacioncode);
                            setup.updateconfig(uservalidate.this);
                            Intent log=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),registrar.class);
                            startActivity(log);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                // The verification code entered was invalid
                                // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                                txtvalidar.setError("Codigo de validacion incorrecto");
                                // [END_EXCLUDE]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Ahora mi pregunta y duda es que como hago para que cuando el usuario sale de la app le estoy dando un singout() como hago para volver a iniciar sesion lo pueda hacer simplemente con el numero de teleno sin tener que mandar el sms con el codigo de verificacion, porque este metodo me funciona pero le al tratar de autenticar ese mismo movil de nuevo me manda el sms con con el codigo de validacion.

Para resumir mi pregunta es como hago para no mandar el sms cada vez que se autentique estos usuarios.

Comment: Estoy tratando de autenticar con Firebase igual que tu. He seguido los pasos del código pero me salen varios errores(en la parte de setup, signInWithPhoneAuthCredential, snackbar, etc), si por favor podrías ayudarme en el tema

Comment: Necesitas que hacer `signout()` para cerrar la aplicación?? No te gustaría dejar la aplicación autenticada aun cuando el usaurio salga?

Comment: Bueno, creo que eso podría ser una solución pero yo quería que el usuario se autenticara cada ves que va a entrar en la app para evitar que otra persona pueda acceder a la cuenta en caso de que le roben el móvil o algo ya que la app va a manejar asuntos financieros.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiestefano Tienes que poner los errores que te da porque nadie te puede ayudar si no saben cual es el error. Solo para ayudarte cuando vayas a pedir ayuda en un foro debes ser siempre lo mas detallado posible en tu pregunta para que te ayuden mas facil.

Comment: En ese caso te conviene más la autenticación por correo electronico. Además podés vincular la cuanta de telefono con la de correo para que sea un solo usuario.